# Task Bar Settings Not Editable with deactivated windows 10

Tags: windows-10, taskbar, display-settings

I have windows 10 x64 authenticated copy but not activated. Thus some basic features are disabled such as the customization of the settings of task bar. Is there a way that I can alter these settings from somewhere else without activating windows?

In particular I want to change the setting for the lock of opened windows in task bar, so when i have more than one windows of the same software open it wont bind them all together but rather show them all as a unique window in task bar.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

A possible solution is to tweak the registry, which should still be enabled without activation.

1. Open regedit (Windows button + R, then type regedit)
2. Go to:

Computer\HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Explorer\Advanced

3. Set the value of TaskbarGlomLevel to 2
4. Restart

I haven't tested this on inactivated Windows, but it should work provided regedit is enabled. Note that once you do activate, it will still show up as 'never combine' when changing the setting through the Settings app.

Comment: Thank you for your reply. Though there is no TaskBarBlomLevel as value there, anything close to that is TaskBarAnimations and TaskbarStateLastRun, or did you mean to create a new value with that name?

Comment: https://prnt.sc/gcg31q please see the attached screenshot. If the key is not present, please create a new key.

Comment: yes i see, i also just checked a pc with authenticated windows 10 and the value exists there.... i will try now to add it.

Comment: i see though that on the authenticated windows 10, which has the never combine activated and the value is set to 1, are you sure that it should be set on 2?

Comment: 0 is always combine, 1 is only combine when taskbar is full, 2 is never combine.

Comment: +1 - it is just because of some great people that there is peace in the world